# Call trigger during SQL Loader insert

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I'm trying to insert data from a file into an Oracle table using SQL loader. The primary key is populated by a sequence where the nextVal is called from an insert trigger.

When I try using sqlldr, it seems to bypass the trigger as it says I cannot insert a null value into the primary key field.

Is there a way I can use sql loader to call the trigger for each insert?

```
OPTIONS (direct=false, SKIP=1)
load DATA
INFILE 'bcbsm.ctl'
append into table pprs.x
(
  LAST_NAME POSITION(1:25) CHAR
)
```

command: `sqlldr username/password control=file.ctl`

In my trigger there is a "Before Insert on x For Each Row" where I call the nextVal for the sequence then assign it to the primary key column. Since it's a unique identifier and populated by a sequence, it's not on the file that I'm trying to load.

Comment: Please show us your SQL*Loader control file and command line, as well as your table definition and some sample data. Which version of Oracle are you on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, I just have to put the sequence's nextVal in quotes in the control file:

```
append into [tablename]
(
   [column name] "[sequence name].nextVal"
   ...
)
```

Comment: Please mark your answer as correct so that others who have the same problem can find help. I know that it will take some time for your to be able to do this.

Comment: Will do @Vérace